# Switch the placement of 2 strings in filename, for all files in the folder with bash

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp

I made a mistake when scraping data, and now my files get allways sorted in the wrong order.
Order in the filename now is DD:MM:YYYY but i need it to be MM:DD:YYYY

Examples of the filenames:

```
07.08.2020-Cf_J-rraZD4.webm      
15.02.2020-KigC0ER_On4.webm      
22.09.2020-m3iAo8SYBko.webm.srt  
30.07.2020-8Qy94fGod_0.webm.srt
07.08.2020-Cf_J-rraZD4.webm.srt  
15.02.2020-KigC0ER_On4.webm.srt
```

Is there a simple way to do this with bash?

edit:

i ended up using his:

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in *.srt ; do
    new=${f:6:4}${f:5:1}${f:3:3}${f:0:3}${f:1:0}${f:11}
    if [[ -f $new ]] ; then
        echo "Can't rename $f: $new already exists!" >&2
    else
        mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion with the `${var:offset:length}` syntax to extract parts of the filenames.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for f in * ; do
    new=${f:3:3}${f:0:2}${f:5}
    if [[ -f $new ]] ; then
        echo "Can't rename $f: $new already exists!" >&2
    else
        mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```

To just generate the new names, you can process the list of old names with sed:

```
sed 's/^\(..\)\.\(..\)/\2.\1/'
```

- `^` matches the start of a string
- `\(..\)` captures two characters, the first such group can be referenced as `\1`, the second one as `\2`.
- `\.` matches a literal dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}.\)\([0-9]\{2\}.\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\2\1\3\4/' input_file
08.07.2020-Cf_J-rraZD4.webm
02.15.2020-KigC0ER_On4.webm
09.22.2020-m3iAo8SYBko.webm.srt
07.30.2020-8Qy94fGod_0.webm.srt
08.07.2020-Cf_J-rraZD4.webm.srt
02.15.2020-KigC0ER_On4.webm.srt
```

With this code, 4 groups are created and returned with back references. Changing the first and second location will change the timestamp order.

Alternatively, using `bash`

```
$ IFS="."; while read -r day month rest; do echo "$month.$day.$rest"; done < input_file
08.07.2020-Cf_J-rraZD4.webm
02.15.2020-KigC0ER_On4.webm
09.22.2020-m3iAo8SYBko.webm.srt
07.30.2020-8Qy94fGod_0.webm.srt
08.07.2020-Cf_J-rraZD4.webm.srt
02.15.2020-KigC0ER_On4.webm.srt
```

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's `rename` of `prename` command:

```
rename -n 's/^(..).(..)/$2.$1/' *.webm*
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

endet up using this:

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in *.srt ; do
    new=${f:6:4}${f:5:1}${f:3:3}${f:0:3}${f:1:0}${f:11}
    if [[ -f $new ]] ; then
        echo "Can't rename $f: $new already exists!" >&2
    else
        mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```

it does dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy.mm.dd

Answer (score -1):

I'm unable to comment on HatLess's post (I think that post incorrectly swapped put the day of the month before the month), but assuming sed is allowed, you can do the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in * ; do
    new=$(echo $f | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}.\)\([0-9]\{2\}\).\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\3.\1\2\4/')
    if [[ -f $new ]] ; then
        echo "Can't rename $f: $new already exists!" >&2
    else
        echo "$f -> $new"
        mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```